# Align components horizontally in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have these two components and i cannot align them horizontally.

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <div>
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 8.4rem;">
        <app-title></app-title>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to align them with:
`display:flex;`
`float:left;`
However, every time I try the sidebar covers title.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
        <div>
            <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div >
            <app-title></app-title>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`

you can use `display: flex` and `justify-content: center`.
If you want to left or right, also you can use `justify-content: start;` or `justify-content: end;`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried but stil the title is behind the side menu i need to use margin-right to show the title

Answer (score 0):

Don't use float, you used flexbox, and flex: 1 to make both children div equally take up the space

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="flex: 1;">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 8.4rem; flex: 1;">
        <app-title></app-title>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also check this out https://flexboxfroggy.com/ it helps me a lot to understand flex when I was starting to learn it